# AWS cli query to get to cloudfront "Domain Name" with specific origin name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

This is my JSON output from awscli I want to get **xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net** using Origin DomainName **example1.com** with AWS cli query only. { I know this filtering with jq, awk and cut, grep }.

```
"DistributionList": {
    "Items": [
        {
            "WebACLId": "", 
            "Origins": {
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "OriginPath": "", 
                        "CustomOriginConfig": {
                            "OriginProtocolPolicy": "http-only", 
                            "HTTPPort": 80, 
                            "HTTPSPort": 443
                        }, 
                        "Id": "DNS for Media Delivery", 
                        "DomainName": "example1.com"
                    }
                ], 
                "Quantity": 1
            }, 
            "DomainName": "xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net", 
         },
        {
            "WebACLId": "", 
            "Origins": {
                "Items": [
                    {
                        "OriginPath": "", 
                        "CustomOriginConfig": {
                            "OriginProtocolPolicy": "http-only", 
                            "HTTPPort": 80, 
                            "HTTPSPort": 443
                        }, 
                        "Id": "DNS for Media Delivery", 
                        "DomainName": "example2.com"
                    }
                ], 
                "Quantity": 1
            }, 
            "DomainName": "yyyyyyyyyy.cloudfront.net", 
         },
       ]
    }
```

Comment: So you need spend time to play with `--filter` option with aws cli.

Comment: I don't think filters are available with cloudfront for AWS CLI

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As AWS CLI `--query` parameter works on top of [JMESPath](http://jmespath.org/) you can build awesome filters. Answer for your question will be:

```
--query "DistributionList.Items[].{DomainName: DomainName, OriginDomainName: Origins.Items[0].DomainName}[?contains(OriginDomainName, 'example1.com')] | [0]"
```

and it will return you:

```
{
  "DomainName": "xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net",
  "OriginDomainName": "example1.com"
}
```

Comment: that was super helpful. Can it only output the domain name so the final output is just `"xxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net"`

Comment: @supersan sure, just change `... | [0]` => `... | [0].DomainName`

Comment: what happens if there are more than one element in `Items` array and we want at least one to match  ? @D.Dimitrioglo

Comment: @Abhijit how it differs from the original question?

Comment: I mean if `Origins.Items` has more than one element. Anyway thanks for the help , Now I figured it out now.

Comment: `--query "DistributionList.Items[].{DomainName: DomainName, OriginDomainName: Origins.Items[?DomainName==\`example1.com\`].DomainName | [0] }[?OriginDomainName!=null]"`